# Insert data to mysql table ends up with blank rows?

Tags: php, mysql

I am displaying all questions from the mysql database.
When i click submit the name, and emailadress is saved correctly.

But question_id and answer_id is just saving blank rows? Why?

I'm i missing something with the sql function for insert the answers?

```
 index.php:

include ('connection.php');

function getQuestions($con) {
// generate all quetions
$query = "SELECT * FROM questions";
$result = @mysqli_query($con, $query);

    if ($result) {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
        $body = $row['question_body'];
        $question_id = $row['question_id'];
        echo '  
            <tr>
                <form action="insert.php" method="POST">
                    <td>'.$question_id, $body.'</td>
                    <td><input type="radio" name="answer_value" value="1"></td>
                    <td><input type="radio" name="answer_value" value="2"></td>
                    <td><input type="radio" name="answer_value" value="3"></td>
             </tr>
                 </form>
                            <br/>';
        }
    }
}
                echo'
                    <form action="insert.php" method="post">
                        Firstname: <input type="text" name="firstname">
                        Lastname: <input type="text" name="lastname">
                        Email: <input type="text" name="email">
                        <input type="submit">
                    </form>';
```

insert.php:

```
    <?php
 include ('connection.php');


 // escape variables for security
 $firstname = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['firstname']);
 $lastname = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['lastname']);
 $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['email']);

 $sql="INSERT INTO users (FirstName, LastName, Email)
 VALUES ('$firstname', '$lastname', '$email')";

if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql)) {
   die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
 }
 echo "User added <br>";


 // escape variables for security
 $question_id = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['question_id']);
 $answer_value = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['answer_value']);

 $sql="INSERT INTO answers (question_id, answer_value)
 VALUES ('$question_id', '$answer_value')"; 

 if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql)) {
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
   }
 echo "Answers added";

mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

Comment: Typo? `form atcion="insert.php"`

Comment: When using `mysqli` you should be using parameterized queries and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) if you make a mistake. Also, unless you have a very good reason, do not use `@` to suppress errors.

Comment: @Vivek thx for your modification. Now it saves the value of the answer but the question_id is still blank?

Comment: @user3906056 Checkout my answer below. Hope that will help !!. You are not submitting question_mark in HTML form. Refer below my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not preparing question_id in your HTML form. It would go something like this :

```
  echo '<tr>
        <form atcion="insert.php" method="post">
            <td><input type="hidden" name="question_id" value="'.$question_id.'">'.$question_id, $body.'</td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="answer_value" value="1"></td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="answer_value" value="2"></td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="answer_value" value="3"></td>
     </tr>
         </form>';
```

Comment: @user3906056 Glap i could help you. Kindly upvote my answr if its helpful fr u.thnx :)

Answer (score 1):

You've got TWO separate forms. The `answer_value` business is defined in the one you create inside your db fetch loop. But your submit button is actually in the other form, where you have the name/email forms.

Only the fields defined *INSIDE* a form tag will get submitted. Fields defined in some completely different `<form>...</form>` block are utterly ignored/unrelated and will not be submitted as well.

In other words, you need

```
<form ...>
    [radio button set for question #1]
    [radio button set for question #2]
    ...
    [input fields for name/email]
</form>
```

Not

```
<form ... >
   [radio button set #1]
</form>
<form ...>
   [radio button set #2]
</form>
<form ...>
   [name/email input fields]
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not submitting the values in your question form. To submit all the entries in one POST, you need all elements on the same form.